# Count of models lists shows 0 when sending a Model List Collection From View to Controller- Asp Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I need to delete the selected rows. Here when I click on delete, the controller action method shows 0 counts for the model item list. Below is my code of HTML and Controller Action

```
@model IEnumerable<XonetPlus_V3.Admin.Models.Articles.ArticleDisplayViewModel>
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Index"; 
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("deleteSelected", "Article", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="col-md-12 m-t-30">
        <div class="card table-card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h5>Articles</h5>
                <div class="card-header-right">

                   <input type="submit" value="delete" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-block pages-block">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>&nbsp;</th>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>Title</th>
                            <th data-breakpoints="xs md">ModifiedBy</th>
                            <th class="action" data-breakpoints="xs md">Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="">
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
                                </td>
                                <td><p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ModifiedBy)</p></td>
                                <td class="action">
                                    <a class="mytooltip" asp-controller="Article" asp-action="edit" 
                                        asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit=</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Can anyone help me to find this issue ?

Comment: provide the controllers code here.for better understanding

Comment: [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> deleteSelected(IList<ArticleDisplayViewModel> collection)
        {

        }

Comment: From the above method, "Collection" parameter return count as zero

Comment: The action method is empty, not surprisingly. You need to put there the logics for deleting selected rows and pass the updated model to the view you return from the controller.e.g. `return View("Index", updatedModel);`. This is quite basic. Rather than asking in Stackoverflow this can be sorted by following a tutorial.

Comment: Why not pass the selected items' ids to the controller?And I think it would be more convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working demo like below:

1.Change your `<input type="checkbox" name="deleteIds" value="@item.Id">`:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="deleteIds" value="@item.Id">
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
        <td><p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ModifiedBy)</p></td>
        <td class="action">
            <a class="mytooltip" asp-controller="Article" asp-action="edit"
                asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit=</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

2.Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> deleteSelected(int[] deleteIds)
{
    foreach(var id in deleteIds)
    {
        var article = await _context.Article.FindAsync(id);
        _context.Article.Remove(article);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

3.Result:
[image]